# Why java.sql.Time.toString() adds hours?

Tags: java

Follow the simple a example

```
java.sql.Time t = new Time(1000);
System.out.println("Time t =" + t);
```

This gives the following output:

```
Time t = 01:00:01
```

While I would expect:

```
Time t = 00:00:01
```

Could someone tell me how to get rid of the hours portion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Time` object is normalized, i.e. the timezone of your JVM is taken into account.

Btw, instead of `toString()` you might want to use `DateFormat#format(Date)` and set the time zone on the DateFormat instance.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should consider your current `TimeZone` and check the API of the constructor

http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html#Time(long)

I expect you are living somewhere in Europe ;-)

Comment: When linking JavaDocs please try to use the current version. Changed it from 1.4.2 to 7 for you :)